# Passing correctly formatted JSON from .NET MVC Controller to View

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc

I'm using vis.js to create a timeline, and am trying to understand where I'm going wrong when trying to pass JSON from my model to the view. The timeline accepts data in JSON format, for example:

```
var data =  [
{"content": "item 1", "start": "2016-08-20"},
{"content": "item 2", "start": "2016-08-21"},
{"content": "item 3", "start": "2016-08-21"}];
```

I have a model the looks like the following:

```
public class MyModel
{
    public ModelData Data { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<TimeLineEntry> Timeline { get; set; } 
    public string ChartData { get; set; }
}
```

In my controller, I'm passing this model to the view as an ActionResult:

```
    public ActionResult Summary(FilterModel filter)
    {
        var modelData = GetModelData(filter);

        var timeline = BuildTimeLine(modelData);

        var chartData = BuildChartData(timeline);

        MyModel model = new MyModel
        {
            ModelData = modelData,
            Timeline = timeline,
            ChartData = chartData
        };

        return View(model); //setting a breakpoint here, ChartData JSON looks 
    }

    private string BuildChartData(List<TimelineEntry> data)
    {
        var timeline = data.Select(a => new
        {
            content = a.Description,
            start = a.CreatedOn
        });

        var jsonSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        return jsonSerializer.Serialize(timeline);
    }
```

In the view, I'm attempting to create a variable to store the JSON for use in the javascript application, like the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  // DOM element for the timeline
    var container = document.getElementById('visualization');

    var data = @Model.ChartData; //I have a feeling I can't define data like this due to the way it is compiled.

    var chartData = JSON.parse(data);
    var items = new vis.DataSet(chartData); //this takes JSON

  var options = {};

  var timeline = new vis.Timeline(container, items, options);
</script>
```

When the page is compiled, I'm getting a javascript error: 
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token &

This happens when I try to store `@Model.ChartData` as a variable; it looks like this when compiled:
   `[{&quot;content&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;start&quot;:&quot;\/Date(1471890279333)\/&quot;},{ ..`..

I feel like this is a simple problem, but I'm currently at a loss as to how to properly pass the JSON from model into the view.

Comment: `var data = @Html.Raw(Json,Encode(Model.ChartData))`

Comment: @StephenMuecke brilliant, thanks. Just to capture a slight typo, this fix worked: `var data = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.ChartData))`

Comment: Fat fingers :). You might also want to consider formatting the date on the server if you want it in that format (e.g `CreatedOn.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the script you can use

```
var data = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.ChartData))
```

however, your wanting an array of objects in the client, which you already have in the controller, so there is little point serializing your collection to a string in the controller and then converting it back to a collection on the client.

Your controller can simply be

```
public ActionResult Summary(FilterModel filter)
{
    var modelData = GetModelData(filter);
    var timeline = BuildTimeLine(modelData);
    var chartData = BuildChartData(timeline);

    MyModel model = new MyModel
    {
        ModelData = modelData,
        Timeline = timeline,
        ChartData = chartData.Select(a => new ChartDataVM
        {
            content = a.Description,
            start = a.CreatedOn
        })
    };
    return View(model); 
}
```

where property ChartData is `public IEnumerable<ChartDataVM> ChartData { get; set; }, and`ChartDataVM` is

```
public class ChartDataVM
{
    public string content { get; set; }
    public DateTime start { get; set; }
}
```

Then in the view, its

```
var data = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.ChartData));
// var chartData = JSON.parse(data); Not required
var items = new vis.DataSet(data);
```

However, based on the format you have indicated that the plugin requires, you may need to change property `start` to typeof `string` and in the query use

```
start = a.CreatedOn.Tostring("yyyy-MM-dd")
```